# How execv gets the output from pipe?

Tags: c, operating-system, execv

referring to the old homework question : `/* implementing  "/usr/bin/ps -ef | /usr/bin/more" */`
using pipes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int fds[2];
  int child[2];
  char *argv[3];
  pipe(fds);
  if (fork()== 0) {
    close(fds[1]);
    close(STDIN_FILENO); dup(fds[0]); /* redirect standard input to fds[1] */
    argv[0] = "/bin/more";
    argv[1] = NULL;           /* check how the argv array is set */
    execv(argv[0], argv);// here how execv reads from stdin ??
    exit(0);


  }
  if (fork() == 0) {
    close(fds[0]);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO); dup(fds[1]);  /* redirect standard output to fds[0] */
    argv[0] = "/bin/ps";
    argv[1] = "-e"; argv[2] = NULL;
    execv(argv[0], argv);
    exit(0);

  }

  close(fds[1]);
  wait(&child[0]);
  wait(&child[0]);  
}
```

After redirecting the fd to standard output, how does execv reads from it. Is it inbuilt in execv that it reads from standard input before executing the command? I am unable to get this concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is based on a false premise -- `execv` doesn't read from anywhere, nor does it need to. It is `more` that reads from the `stdin` it inherits across the call to `execv`. The reason `more` reads from `stdin` is because it's a filter and, like most filters, it defaults to reading from `stdin` if another input source isn't specified on the command line. (Otherwise, `/usr/bin/ps -ef | /usr/bin/more` wouldn't work.)

Comment: Thank you sir! That's correct. I was thinking in wrong direction. Now I got it. That's why a command like " ps | ls" will print only the output of ls.

Answer (score 0):

In your second `fork` call, I would change the code from this:

```
  if (fork() == 0) {
    close(fds[0]);
```

to this:

```
  close(fds[0]);
  if (fork() == 0) {
```

The `argv[1]` for the `ps` call should be `-ef`.

All programs will read from `stdin` to get terminal input and write to `stdout` to deliver data to the terminal, if they do not do anything to change the default settings for those streams. What the code is doing is modifying `stdin` for `more` and modifying `stdout` for `ps`. The `stdout` for `more` is the same as the current process (the parent). Thus, your program is redirecting `ps` terminal output data to be the terminal input for `more`.

The `pipe` call returns two file descriptors that are connected to each other unidirectionally. When `ps` writes to its `stdout`, it is going to the `dup`d `fds[1]`. When `more` reads from its `stdin`, it is the `dup`d `fds[0]`. So, `more` picks up the output of `ps`.